# How to combine Flux and Mono

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

Assume we have the following function

```
fun getAnnualData(tenant: String): Flux<DashboardResponse> {

    val year = LocalDate.now().year

    val annualExpenses = expenseFinder.sumAllByYearAndTenant(year = year, tenant = tenant)
    val warehouseExpenses = expenseFinder.sumWarehouseByYearAndTenant(year = year, tenant = tenant)
    val annualRevenues = revenueFinder.sumAllByYearAndTenant(year = year, tenant = tenant)
    
    return annualExpenses.zipWith(annualRevenues)
        .filter { it.t1._id?.year == year }
        .filter { it.t2._id?.year == year }
        .map {
            DashboardResponse(
                period = Period.ANNUAL,
                expenses = it.t1,
                revenue = it.t2
            )
        }
}
```

and I want to add the `warehouseExpenses` to the returning value. How would I do that?

Where

- annualExpenses = Flux
- warehouseExpenses = Mono
- annualRevenue = Flux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `flatMap` to combine Mono:

```java
Flux.just(...).zipWith(Flux.just(...))
        .filter(...)
        .flatMap(tuple -> Mono.just(true).map(m -> new DashboardResponse(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2(), m)));
```